# Automatic redirection from child component to parent component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I currently have a problem with angular routing.

When I try to access the child path of a component loaded with lazy load, the path appears in the address bar for a very small instant and immediately after, it redirects to the parent component's path.

Example, if I want to access localhost:4200/dummy/table, it redirects to localhost:4200/dummy, if I try to navigate through a [routerLink].

**If I directly enter localhost:4200/dummy/table in the address bar, it loads the module correctly and displays the child component.**

Cleaning up the code a bit to simplify the example my menu would look something like this

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of menu" [routerLink]="item.url"> 
      {{ item.title }} 
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.children" [routerLink]="[item.url, subItem.url]">
            {{ subItem.title }}
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the rest of the code if you do not mind I put it as images

app-routing:
[image]

dummy-module:
[image]

menu.json:
[image]

Does anyone know what could be happening to me?

According to the {enableTracing: true} it enters the route but exits it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the nested elements, the parent and the child both have the `routerLink` attribute set.    I suggest wrapping the parent in a span or an anchor tag to remove the nesting of the `routerLinks`. An example is provided below.

````
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of menu"> 
      <span [routerLink]="item.url"> {{ item.title }} </span>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let subItem of item.children" [routerLink]="[item.url, subItem.url]">
            {{ subItem.title }}
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>```
````